# Getting FAGLL03H report using pyrfc

Tags: python-3.x, sap-erp, saprfc, pyrfc

This is a mixed question between SAP and the usage of the pyrfc module. I need to use the `FAGLL03H` transaction code (tcode) to replicate a G/L report into a database on a daily basis. Now, the thing is that `FAGLL03H` is not a table per se, but a G/L Account Line Item Browser (G/L View), so I need to access that Tcode and pass a series of parameters in order to get the information we need.

1. How can I use the RFC protocol to access that tcode and generate a report?
2. is it possible to do (1) through pyrfc?

This is the code I use to consult tables:

```
import pyrfc
from pprint import PrettyPrinter


conn = pyrfc.Connection(ashost=...)

options = [{'TEXT': "FCURR = 'USD'"}]
pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
ROWS_AT_A_TIME = 10
rowskips = 0

while True:
    print(u"----Begin of Batch---")
    result = conn.call('RFC_READ_TABLE', \
                       QUERY_TABLE='TCURR', \
                       OPTIONS=options, \
                       ROWSKIPS=rowskips, ROWCOUNT=ROWS_AT_A_TIME)
    pp.pprint(result['DATA'])
    rowskips += ROWS_AT_A_TIME

    if len(result['DATA']) < ROWS_AT_A_TIME:
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No way
2. No

The main point you need to understand is the difference between [SAP transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-code) (tcode) and [SAP RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Function_Call). The difference is huge and makes it impossible to use them in the similar manner. You are trying to call FAGLL03H report like a table via `RFC_READ_TABLE`, but it is not a table, it is much more, it is a transaction.

SAP tcode is nothing than a shortcut in SAP that points to some program, usually GUI program, and can contain **hundreds** of modules, including RFC-enabled ones. And some of these modules are internal and have no RFC equivalent, so it is impossible to call them remotely, at least but not the last it is necessary to know how to call them (in what order) and which parameters to pass.

SAP RFC is like a container for ABAP code (but also [a protocol](https://www.guru99.com/rfc-remote-function-call.html) for calling this code) which implements some functionality, either a small piece like converting characters' case or converting measure units, or huge one, for example posting financial documents and creating enterprise hierarchy objects like workcenters, cost centers, sales organizations, etc. RFC-modules can be likened to Python modules or Java methods and they are usually implemented for one single task, and are usually used not standalone but in combination with other methods.

The above-mentioned transaction is huge and is intended for output of G/L account lines and cannot be called via PyRFC. PyRFC [features](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC) are limited to calling only RFC-modules from which `FAGLL03H` consists of.

The only thing you can do here is to find *equivalent* function modules which returns the same items as `FAGLL03H`. Possible candidates:

- BAPI_GLX_GETDOCITEMS
- FAGL_GET_OPEN_ITEMS_GL
- FAGL_GET_OPEN_ITEMS_KU
- FAGL_GET_OPEN_ITEMS_LI
- FAGL_GET_OPEN_ITEMS
- FKK_GL_LINE_ITEMS_SELECT
- BAPI_AP_ACC_GETBALANCEDITEMS
- BAPI_AR_ACC_GETBALANCEDITEMS
- BAPI_AP_ACC_GETOPENITEMS
- BAPI_AR_ACC_GETOPENITEMS

You should try each and compare the output with your tcode, if it is identical. Only after then you can use PyRFC to call them.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check this in order to get all the specific Tables:

https://www.recercat.cat/bitstream/handle/2072/5419/PFCLopezRuizAnnex3.pdf?sequence=4

You can then either build from there or create a Report (transaction SQ01) and execute through RSAQ_REMOTE_QUERY_CALL.
Your business requirements should decide your code, not the opposite.