# Get SMQ queues in Python?

Tags: python, saprfc, pyrfc

I'm using the PYRFC library and so far I've managed to connect to SAP.

```
conn = Connection(ashost='xxxxxxxxx', sysnr='02', client='100', user='xxxxx', passwd='xxxxxxxx.')
result = conn.call('STFC_CONNECTION', REQUTEXT=u'Hello SAP!')
print (result)
```

I did the connection test and everything was ok. But now I'm trying to run the queues created in SAP.

[image]

I performed some tests, trying to simulate the F8 but without success.
Is there any way to make this execution using via python?

Comment: `trying to simulate the F8 but without success` what success do you expect? you are trying to run SMQ1/SMQ2 functionality from PyRFC?

Comment: actually I needed to know how to run them by pyrfc. In the interface I use F8 to execute, but I would like to understand how it works through the pyrfc lib

Answer (score 0):

Directly you cannot query SMQ1/2 results, for an extended explanation read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60097959/911419).

To get the SMQ results in Pyton you need to find a module with an equivalent functionality, and good news pa-pam!, I did it for you: this is **TRFC_QIN_GET_CURRENT_QUEUES** function module.

How to call you can find it in any pyrfc tutorial. Probable sample:

```
def func():
    import pyrfc
    from pyrfc import Connection
    conn=pyrfc.Connection(user='', passwd='', ashost='', etc.)

    queue_name = '*'
    client     = '100'

    result=con.call("TRFC_QIN_GET_CURRENT_QUEUES", qname=queue_name, 
                                                   client=client)
print(result['QVIEW'])
```

all you need to put here is queue name (`qname` parameter) and `client` value ([what is it?](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/bwpluginsap/8.2.2/doc/html/GUID-6A98DBB1-9681-42A7-899F-F30C9E7E8E44.html)).